# Implementing many to many relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables

1.**Rectangle**(rectId , xPos , yPos , height , width)

2.**Scale**(scaleId , someothercols...)

Now each column in the rectangle can have  ' 0 to 1 ' scale associated with it.

i.e xPos can have a scale,yPos can have a scale and so on . So in general a single rectangle can have more than one scales.

Also all the above columns can also have no scale reference, in that case they would have a static value i.e xPos=50,yPos=60 so on..

Also a scale can be referenced by more than one rectangle .

What is the best way to implement this in sql

The way I thought of is having a junction table Rectangle_scale with rect_column attribute exg :

**Rectangle_scale**

```
| rectScaleId | rectId      | scaleId      | rect_col(string)|
|:----------- |------------:|:------------:|---------------- | 
| 1           |      1      |     2        |  Xpos           |
| 2           |      1      |     3        |  Ypos           | 
| 3           |      2      |     2        |  Height         |
```

Is this the right way to do this? Also do I need the rectScaleId col , or should I use rectId and scaleId as a composite primary key

Also, something to mentioned which is not directly related to the quesion, I am using Laravel 5.2 framework with eloquent, not necessarily required, but the solution which adheres to the limitation of Laravel's eloquent would be nice.

Comment: I think what you have here is a good setup. I also like having an ID column in every table. You technically don't have to have one in rectangle_scale, but I think it makes updating/deleting records from that table easier.

Comment: That's a good choice I'll also suggest  you to use the coupe referenced rectangle id and referenced scale id as the primary  key of the conjunction table, having rectScaleId column is just redundant, think about every possible choice even if a rectangle has to have more than one scale the union of the two id's would always be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Many to Many relations require a conjunction table as you say.

So according to your question the relation is fundamentally between `rectange` table and `scale` table.

### Properties we need the tables to have:

- every **scale** can be **referenced** as many as needed by any of the existent rectangles
- every **rectangle** can be **associated** with more than one scale

This can be accomplished by creating the tables as follows:

```
create table rectangle (
  rectID int primary key auto_increment,
  xPos int,
  yPos int, 
  height int,
  width int)ENGINE = Innodb;

create table scale (
  scaleID int primary key auto_increment,
  descr text )ENGINE = Innodb;

create table rect_scale (
  scale int not null,
  rect int ,
  rect_col varchar(100),
  primary key (scale,rect),
  foreign key(scale) references scale(scaleID),
  foreign key(rect) references rectangle(rectID)     
)ENGINE = Innodb;
```

I've also created a demo on SQLFiddle: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8be1a2/2)

Comment: I did this but then I went back to drop the many to many row idea as the framework I am working on make it a difficult to work on relatonship like these

Comment: You have to create the mapping between the tables and your models

Comment: Laravel 5.2 , as far as I know it doesn't support composite PK, also  not sure how I would implement the third column i.e rect_col using laravels manay to many relationship model implementation

Comment: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/06/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an intermediate table, your xPos and yPos could be foreign keys to the scale table like this:

```
CONSTRAINT xpos_scale_fk FOREIGN KEY(xpos) REFERENCES scale(scaleId) 
CONSTRAINT ypos_scale_fk FOREIGN KEY(ypos) REFERENCES scale(scaleId)
```

But you will need to create records in the scale table for that case:

> Also all the above columns can also have no scale reference ,in that case they would have a static value i.e xPos=50,yPos=60 so on..

I don't completely understand what values you have in scale table but I would normalize your data so that xpos and ypos always have same kind of data -- references to scale. That way you could avoid more complicated setup of one more intermediate table.

So it would look like this (if I correctly understood your problem):

```
rectangle
rect_id, xpos, ypos, height, width
1, 0, 1, 2, 2

scale
scale_id, units, values
0, pixels, 50
1, pixels, 100
2, meters, 2
```

Then perhaps next step would be to decompose scale into units and values.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but if I do that how would I handle the above case ,i.e no scale reference but static values,

Comment: I think I would add them into scales table.

Comment: but the scale table itself can be reference by more than one rectangles

Comment: Your setup is also valid but a bit more complicated. Because you have a relation both on scaleId and rectCol.

Comment: If rectangle table has 2 foreign keys (xpos and ypos) to scale table that's okay. One scale could be referenced by more than one rectangle, foreign key need not be unique.

Comment: I agree, but I sill can't get  my head around how I would store the static value ,can't store that in the scale table as it referenced by more than one rect,

Comment: I added an example of how I see it. Note that the rectangle has scale(scale_id = 2) for the height and width, so that's a square in fact. And scale_id=2 means 2 meters.

Comment: Another option. If you could assume your dimensions have the same scale (e.g. meters, or pixels) but different values, you could add additional scale column to your rectangle table. So that there are rect_id, xpos, ypos, xyscale, height, width, hwscale. Where xpos/ypos, height/width store values, and scale stores additional information. So now you have more options :)